# SQL: Using a partition as a condition in a sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT
    price_band
    ,device
    ,SUM(requests) as requests
From database.price_band_stats
WHERE
    day = '2016-10-31'
    AND product_id = 6584
    and device IN ('Desktop', 'Android')    
GROUP BY
    price_band
    ,device
```

That returns a table that looks like:

```
|price_band | device  | requests
0             Android   149007
0.01          Android   466467
0.05          Android   520661
0.1           Android   487273
0             Desktop   319786
0.01          Desktop   1485894
0.05          Desktop   1693395
0.1           Desktop   1547485
```

I want to adjust my code to add an extra column. The new column would sums all the requests with a greater than or equal price band for a given device. For example, if we take the price band 0.05 on Android, I want the sum of all requests to Android with a price band of 0.05 or higher (i.e. 0.05 and 0.1)

So the table would look like:

```
price_band      device     requests    request_above_price_band
0               Android    149007      1623408
0.01            Android    466467      1474401
0.05            Android    520661      1007934
0.1             Android    487273      487273
0               Desktop    319786      5046560
0.01            Desktop    1485894     4726774
0.05            Desktop    1693395     3240880
0.1             Desktop    1547485     1547485
```

Comment: I don't understand all, but one suggestion is to create 2 temporary tables. The first one will hold the results of your existing request, and the second one will hold the results with the extra column you want to add. You can then inner join the 2 temporary tables.

Comment: this bit: "where the price band is greater than or equal to the price band in question." is especially curvy

Comment: Hi. I thought the results table might help clarify this. If we take the price band 0.05 on Android for example, I want the sum of all requests to Android with a price band of 0.05 or higher (i.e. 0.05 and 0.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [window function SUM with ORDER BY DESC and partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
WITH T AS
( SELECT
    price_band
    ,device
    ,SUM(requests) as requests
 From database.price_band_stats
 WHERE
    day = '2016-10-31'
    AND product_id = 6584
    and device IN ('Desktop', 'Android')    
 GROUP BY
    price_band,device
)
SELECT
 price_band, 
 device, 
 requests,
 SUM(requests) OVER (PARTITION BY device  ORDER BY price_band DESC) 
    as request_above_price_band 
 FROM T
ORDER BY device,price_band
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ae64/3)</kbd>

Comment: Hi. This almost works... in the WITH section that creates T, we need 'device' as well in the Group By. Once I put this in in works perfectly! Can you add this change and I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks!